# Err: QueryFailedError: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have a class where I save some of the values to my db using TypeORM but I get this problem: `Err: QueryFailedError: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`. I have synchronize: true in mu ormconfig file and I've tested dropping the table entirely and letting TypeORM create it and it does but it gives me the same error, any idea on what might be happening or how to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to save a momentJS object as a date and it crashed. Transform the momentJS to Date before saving the object and it solved the issue.